# Android Gradle Libraries Conflict

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, dependencies

I'm trying to implement Firebase dynamic links in an application that already uses Firebase, but once I added the needed libraries for dynamic links I started receiving this error:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[19.0.
  2]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.
```

these are the old dependencies related to Firebase that were previously used in the app:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:24.0.1'
```

and these are the new ones I'm trying to add:

```
// Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.0.0')

// Declare the dependencies for the Dynamic Links and Analytics libraries
// When using the BoM, you don't specify versions in Firebase library dependencies
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links-ktx'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
```

I'm not sure which dependency the error is referring to that need to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use the [Firebase BoM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/learn-more#bom):

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.0.0')
```

you should specify **all** of your Firebase depedencies without version numbers, and let the BoM assign them, so that they are all compatible with each other.  This means stripping off the version numbers for the dependencies you added for FCM and others:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision'
```

I don't know about `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'` - you might have to make sure that one is manually up to date to the latest version.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried to remove the version from all firebase dependencies and updated the play-services-auth dependency to the latest version but still got the same error